# How to find the data in mongodb using golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

In this code, I am trying to find the data from MongoDB based on the `userID`. But whenever I run this code, it gives me an error that `mongo: no documents in result`.

I wrote `db.dataStored.findOne({_id: ObjectId("60a60718503219dfd740f9fe")})` in mongo shell also but it gave me a `null` result. Although the data is present in the MongoDB database. Here is the picture to see.

[image]

```
userID := "60a60718503219dfd740f9fe"
var result Trainer

collection := client.Database("PMS").Collection("dataStored")
err = collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"_id": userID}).Decode(&result)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("Found a single document: %+v\n", result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for a string `_id`, but `_id` is an `ObjectId`.

```
objectId, err:=primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(userID)
collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"_id": objectId}).Decode(&result)
```